# "Alive in the next minute"

Tags: grammaticality, articles, spoken-english

Consider the following sentences:

> 1. We ourselves don't know whether we'll be alive in the next minute.
> 2. We ourselves don't know whether we'll be alive in next minute.
> 3. We ourselves don't know whether we'll be alive next minute.

Out of these three, which one will used by a native speaker? I'm not sure which is grammatically correct. I think the first one is correct, but I'm not sure about that. It's for spoken English, not written English.

The context is simple: A few friends are stuck in a bad situation (or place) and anyone can die at any time. So one guy says the above statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would make these changes:

- add the verb (I think you meant to do that anyway),
- drop the *ourselves*,
- change the *whether* to *if*,
- add the word *still*, and
- include a preposition in the final phrase:

> *We don't know if we'll still be alive in the next minute*.

The inclusion of *ourselves* isn't grammatically incorrect, but it makes the sentence unnecessarily wordy.

Similarly, there's nothing wrong with *whether* in that sentence, but I think *if* sounds a little more natural.

In my mind, the word *still* adds a small bit of tension to the scene. Obviously, the characters are alive now, the issue is whether or not they will **still** be alive a minute from now.

As for the preposition (which is the crux of your question), *next minute* by itself sounds like it's missing a word, at least to my native ear, so I prefer *in the next minute*.

A rewording you might consider would be:

> *We don't know if we'll still be alive a minute from now*.

The phrase *a minute from now* is often used to allude to the immediate future. Here's a quote:

> *I remind us: the future begins a minute from now*. (Helen Harris Perlman, 1989)

Comment: "Ourselves" emphasizes that it is "we" who don't know rather than someone else. If in context you have just been talking about what others know, then saying "we ourselves" emphasizes the "we". Whether that's good or useful depends on the larger context.

Comment: @Jay: That's true; good point. Consider the soldiers talking in the foxholes: "The government and the generals are telling us everything is going to be okay. We ourselves wonder if we'll still be alive tomorrow." In that context, I'd leave the _ourselves_ in the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, there's no reason why OP's usage should be any different with other time-frames for which it's easier to find examples. Replacing ***year*** with ***minute***, results from Google Books show that native speakers almost always choose OP's version #3...

> 1a: ...be alive in the next year [(90 results)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22whether%20I%27ll%20be%20alive%20next%20year%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22be%20alive%20the%20next%20year%22&tbm=bks)
>    2a: ...be alive in next year [(0 results)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22whether%20I%27ll%20be%20alive%20next%20year%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22be%20alive%20in%20next%20year%22&tbm=bks)
>    3a: ...be alive next year [(3700 results)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22whether%20I%27ll%20be%20alive%20next%20year%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22be%20alive%20next%20year%22&tbm=bks)

---

Note that in OP's context, *next minute/year/etc.* identifies a specific period of time in the future (the *minute/year **after** the current minute/year*). This isn't quite the same as the similar construction ***in/within*** the next minute/year, which identifies a period of time *one minute/year long, starting from **now***. Thus,...

> 1b: He will die in the next year [(4700 results)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22whether%20I%27ll%20be%20alive%20next%20year%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22will%20die%20in%20the%20next%20year%22&tbm=bks)
>    2b: He will die in next year [(2 results)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22whether%20I%27ll%20be%20alive%20next%20year%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22will%20die%20in%20next%20year%22&tbm=bks)
>    3b: He will die next year [(5830 results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22whether%20I%27ll%20be%20alive%20next%20year%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22will%20die%20next%20year%22&tbm=bks)

The reason format #1 occurs much more often there is because *dying* can be seen as an "event" which may occur *at some particular point **within** a specified time-frame*, whereas in OP's context, *being alive* is more an "ongoing state" that may (or may not) continue ***throughout*** that time-frame.

To summarise, OP's #2 is non-idiomatic in *all* contexts. Whether ***in the*** is used or not largely depends on whether the speaker is talking about an **event** that may occur before some specified time-period has elapsed, or about some **condition** that may or may not be true during some future time-frame.

Answer (score 0):

You need a verb. Of the three, best is probably:

> We ourselves don't know whether we'll be alive next minute.